# Best way to perform plotting with matplotlib to achieve OHLC like plots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, mplfinance

The library [mplfinance](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance) offers a good possibility to perform OHLC plotting with Python/Matplotlib. Nevertheless I want to / have to build a small application that does a kind of OHLC plotting by itself.

I am wondering how I should perform the (huge) amount of vertical and horizontal bars by myself.

Is it the best to do a `plt.plot()` for all the data I have or is there a more performant way to do this using matplotlib?

Snippet of `mplfinance` output

[image: snippet of mplfinance output]

Comment: I think you should start by reading and understanding the code for `mplfinance`. I mean if everything you want is already posted on github, just copy / imitate what you need. I'm voting to close this question as it's not clear what you're asking for.

Comment: I agree with @Asmus **read the code!**  mplfinance uses maplotlib collections (line collections for OHLC lines, and poly collections (polygon) for candles).  Collections are the most performant want to use matplotlib when drawing *a lot* of similar items in various places on the plot.

Comment: Why was this question closed?   Seems to me perfectly clear with enough detail.  Whoever closed it, please re-open.